# Add custom back stack

Tags: android

`mSearchWrapper` is a view which contains a `EditTextView`. `mSearchWrapper` becomes `visible` and `gone`.

When it becomes `visible` I show the keyboard and request focus to the EditTextView:

```
private void showInput() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
}
```

At this point the user can press the **back** button and close the keyboard. I want to create "here" a back stack where: on back pressed not only does the keyboard gets hidden but the `mSearchWrapper` as well (`mSearchWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);`).

*How can I have both the already keyboard-hidden backstack and the setVisibility(View.GONE) in one back-pressed event?*

(alternative: *how can I add some code in that specific existing backstack?*)

Should I rewrite the whole backstack in that activity as [shown here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#SynthesizeBackStack)?

Comment: What if you override onBackPressed()?

Comment: @shkschneider On first back it closes only the keyboard. On second back it sets the visibility to Gone and some seconds after it closes the app (since there nothing else in the stack).

Comment: So you can implements what you want there and return true. This answers your question "add custom back stack": just override onBackPressed(). The rest is another thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was helped by [this example](http://emumair.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/how-to-override-android-back-key-when-soft-keyboard-is-open/).

I extended the editext class inside the Activity like: `private class HidableEditText extends EditText` and moved all the attributes from XML programmatically (to add the view programmatically).

Then I overrode the `onKeyPreIme`:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            mSearchWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode,event);
    }
```

`super` does the work to hide the keyboard for me (and the stacking) so I only had to adjust the visibility.